# How to add regular class lib reference in ASP.NET 5 and Visual Studio 2015 CTP?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/01/16/asp-net-5-in-visual-studio-2015-ctp-5.aspx you should now be able to include regular class libraries to asp.net 5/vnext projects.

When I use the add reference the package.config is updated so it looks something like this:

```
...
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "ClassLib": "1.0.0-*"
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": { }
},
...
```

Everything looks fine in Visual Studio and intellisense works, but it fails to build. I get the CS103 error (The name 'xxxx' does not exist in the current context). Any ideas?

Also, is it supposed to work when targeting core as well?

Comment: Try referencing it without version    "ClassLib": ""   Also make sure that you have selected full version of .Net framework in project properties because that's where you are adding your reference.

Comment: @PankajKapare, already tried that with no luck.

Comment: Do you try to reference compiled libraries or class library projects? Only the former works

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci, I only tried to reference a library project.

Comment: Pankaj stated: "Also make sure that you have selected full version of .Net framework in project properties [WHAT project? the web project or the class library project???] because that's where you are adding your reference. " In addition to that question, I can't see within the starter web project where you can change the targeted framework (I've disabled the aspnetcore, trying to only target full .net). Help?

Comment: My understanding, nuget packages are the unit of dependency from ASP.NET 5 onwards. So you would need to produce a Nuget package having those dlls and depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the newly released Visual Studio 2015 CTP I was just now able to:

1. Create a new "ASP.NET 5 starter App" project.
2. Add a new normal (not ASP.NET 5) class library project to the solution created from step 1.
3. Added a static method public static DateTime Foo.GetTime() in the class library.
4. Added ClassLibrary1.Foo.GetTime().ToString() to the home index view.

Everything compiled and ran, displaying the time value returned by the class library.

(Note:  I'm ensuring that I'm not using a Core runtime.  I'm pretty sure projects using the Core runtime can only use .dlls built against the Core runtime.)

Comment: As of CTP6, this doesn't appear to work. The type is not visible from the vNext project despite being able to add the class library to references (and it showing up in the project.json file).

Comment: I also can't get this to work in CTP6.  I added the reference, it showed up in my project.json file inside frameworks.aspnet50 node, but I can't compile, it says it can't find the library.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently and was able to resolve it by changing the Target Framework on my class library to 4.5.1. By default, class library projects will use 4.5.2. When you attempt to add the reference to your ASP.NET 5 project it will attempt to put it in the DNX 4.5.1 bucket, and with a 4.5.2 project that does not work.

Comment: This does not work. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868780/shared-class-library-references-for-asp-net-5-beta-7