# Shared Class Library References for ASP.NET 5 beta 7

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

In our current environment, we have some shared common library (C# Class Library .NET 4.5.1 csproj) projects that are referenced by both asp.net and console applications. We are looking into upgrading 1 of our web projects to ASP.NET 5 to start testing out some of the new changes coming.

Since I can't do a project reference in ASP.NET 5 to the old csproj library type, I have to reference the library by it's compiled DLL and remove dnxcore50 from project.json (which is fine for us). However, We own the shared library source and constantly bring down updates in our DEV environment for modifications and changes will be needed often to the DLL. ASP.NET 5 puts the DLL inside of a lib directory and does not use a path to the csproj directory.

What would you do if you have asp.net & console csproj apps along with asp.net 5 apps needing to share a common code library without having to maintain 2 code bases?  Would you recommend a build task to compile the common library project and replace the reference DLL in lib before compiling the asp.net 5 project or instead setup a local nuget repo for our shared library since project references are out of the question now for csproj? We're a shared team with all of this code in TFS so whatever I do needs to be replicated easily for everyone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shared code doesn't change to often, I would go with a shared nuget repository. This way, you get all the benefits of using nuget packages: versioning, easy restoration, etc. Your solution can have less projects and compile faster. 
But if the shared code is constantly changed, going through pack-push-restore process could be painfull.

There is one other way - `dnu` has a handy command named `wrap`. It wraps your existing `.csproj` files into `project.json` files that can be then referenced by aspnet5 projects.

You can do something like this:

1. Add a [`global.json`](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html#the-global-json-file) file in the some top-level directory that contains your projects. In the `projects` section, list directories that contain your source-code, for example:

   ```json
   {
       "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
       "sdk": {
           "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the same directory that contains `global.json` execute `dnu wrap` for each existing `.csproj` project.

   ```
   dnu wrap src/my.project/my.project.csproj
   ```

   This should create a directory `wrap` containing `project.json` files that wrap `.csprojs`. A sample file  looks like this:

   ```json
   {
       "version": "1.0.0-*",
       "frameworks": {
           "net45": {
               "wrappedProject": "../../src/my.project/my.project.csproj",
               "bin": {
                   "assembly": "../../src/my.project/obj/{configuration}/my.project.dll",
                   "pdb": "../../src/my.project/obj/{configuration}/my.project.pdb"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that `wrap` directory is also added to `projects` section in `global.json`.
3. In your solution, add a new aspnet project and add a reference to the wrapped project. Just add:

   ```json
   "my.project": ""
   ```

   to `dependencies` section. Aspnet should automatically pick up `global.json` file in root directory, and will look for projects in all directories listed there, including `wrap` directory.
4. Now you're good to go - you can use all classes from `my.project`, step into them while debugging, go to definition, etc. Note that in your solution, you still have the old `csproj`.

You can find a sample code here: https://github.com/heavymetaldev/aspnet5-wrap.

I suppose this may get a little complicated if you have some custom things in your projects, like conditional compilation, custom includes, etc.